# How to disable Gitlab webui sign-UP authentication in Helm Chart ? (and without using gitlab rails console)

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I want to know how to disable Gitlab webui sign-UP authentication in Helm Chart. I see no directive associated to sign-up at https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/charts/globals.html.

Have you got an idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think the chart gets into that level of granularity, as it's not trying to replicate every single GitLab API resource and option. Whatever mechanism you are using to install the chart will likely have to take care about mutating the install after it is successful

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed the Helm Chart does not seem to be the good tool to manage this point of Gitlab settings. Now, i'm trying to use API for this.